# With two groups in dplyr output I want second group to be in descending order

Tags: r, dplyr

[Input data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7mskbvjpxtqit7t/testdata.csv?dl=0) from Excel file

Desired Output[[image: Output]]

Here is the code I am using:

I read the test input into the data frame 'noah5yrs'. Then, in the output for each year, I want 'Year' to be in ascending order but 'winloss' to be in descending order. How can I do that?

```
noah5yrs %>% mutate(winloss = substring(Rslt,1,1)) %>% group_by(Year, winloss) %>% summarize(mean_GSc = mean(GSc, na.rm=TRUE), sdGSc = sd(GSc, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Comment: %>% arrange(Year,desc(winloss)) , sorry did not see that your winloss is factor

Comment: Thanks StupidWolf. That is what I needed to know.

Comment: With such a small data sample, why not just post the data as in the question so folks don't have to download from a third party? And include the desired output as text instead of a picture? See the [guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on reproducible R posts